# file reading in java- converting every line to an existing function

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner

I have an input text file that contains different commands that I need to do,
the commands have to be done one by one, and I don't know-how.
I thought of just reading the text file--->putting the current line in a string and then comparing it with all the commands which is very not efficient

thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're fairly new to programming. If that's the case, then the best advice I can give you: ignore "efficient" for now. Getting things to work and make sense is **way** more important at this point than any kind of efficiency (the machine you test this on is probably several magnitudes more powerful than necessary for your tasks, so efficiency isn't important yet).

Comment: @JoachimSauer could you still tell me the best way?

Comment: There is no "best way" to code anything.  Aim for code that can be read and understood by most programmers.

Comment: There is no "best way", as Gilbert mentioned. Or put differently: what the best way is will vary **massively** based on many external factors (specific requirements, skill level of developers, life-time of solution, ...). In some cases a naive-easily-written solution that's hard to maintain is best, because it's quick to write and not expected to be maintained for long. Another time a complex, but easier to extend solution could be better, because it's the base of a project that's to be maintained/improved for a long time. For now, forget about "best" and focus on getting something to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to read commands from a file.
A lot depends on the format of commands and if they have parameters or not.

Here are possible solutions.

**One command per row in a text file**

Save in the file row by row the sequence of commands. Read the file row by row and check each row with a list of commands.

Pro:

- Easy to implement

Cons:

- Not easy to handle parameters
- Difficult to handle blocks of commands
- Difficult to handle jumps between commands

**Commands saved as json objects**

Hold the file as a text file having a single json array where each item holds a command, eventually with parameters.

Pro

- Quite easy using libraries to parse json files
- Easy to handle parameters

Cons

- A list of commands as json array is less readable than a structured programming language

**Create a parser and your own programming language**

You can create your own programming language having only the details that you need.

Pro

- This solution fit very well any need that you can have
- Easy to read because you can decide the structure that you like more
- Speed of code
- Is possible to handle typical programming construct like loops, conditional statements, blocks of code...

Cons

- Very hard to implement, you need to define your own language and implement it using a custom parser (example using ANTLR4)